# Need help restoring GRUB settings to default settings

Tags: 11.04, grub2

I'm running 11.04 and decided to spend my winter break tweaking Grub until I could boot directly into tty1 and I got turned around somewhere.

I still boot into tty7 but I have two new problems.

The first is, while Ubuntu is loading, instead of the Ubuntu logo or any information about what processes are being started, I get a flashing cursor in the top left of my screen. The graphical login from tty7 will eventually load up but, until it does, all I can see if the flashing cursor.

The second problem that I have is the screen resoluton on my other tty's has been changed. It looks like it's about 640 x 48. I believe that it had been around 1280 x 720 before.

At this point, I'm just interested in returning Grub to the default settings that existed when I installed 11.04.

Here's a copy of my Grub configuration for reference.

Quote:
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
    # /boot/brug/grub.cfg
    # For full documentation of options in this file see:
    # info -f grub -n 'Simple confuration'

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMD_LINE=" vga=775 splash"

#Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernal that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567, 0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

#Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command 'vbeinfo'
# GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

#Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

#Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

#Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

If this helps, these are the commands that GRUB is entering before I boot. I got this information by pressing the E key at the GRUB menu:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-13-generic'

recordfail
set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
insmod par_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(dev/sda,msdos5)'
seach --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4153ea84-7423-49a3-8eb80-4007a4326dda
linux /vmlinux-2.6.38-13-generic root=UUID=914b61f6-c063-4df1-a0c3-99e4b6022b7 ro vga=775 splash quiet splash ipv6.disable=1 vt.handoff=7
initrd /initrd.img-2.6.38-13-generic
```

Comment: you might try "sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub2" - however, it might not only be grub2 which is misconfigured.

Comment: I tried that. I get "Package 'grub2' is not installed and no info is available. Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files, and dkpg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents. /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: grub2 is not installed."

Comment: GRUB_CMD_LINE=" vga=775 splash"  replace the line with GRUB_CMD_LINE="" or  GRUB_CMD_LINE="nomodeset"

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. Thank you so much. Was there some sort of conflict between "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable=1"" and "GRUB_CMD_LINE=" vga=775 splash"" that was causing my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments

> GRUB_CMD_LINE=" vga=775 splash" replace the line with GRUB_CMD_LINE="" or GRUB_CMD_LINE="nomodeset"